Deneb Vega-Lite : concatenated view dynamic height/width change
is it possible to dynamically change the height/width of containers in Deneb when concatenating views (hconcat/vconcat)?
I tried few approaches, like for example below but I'm stuck here.
"height": {"expr": "datum['selected_granularity'] === 0 ? 200 : 180"}

sample code:
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"category": "A", "value": 10}
        ]
      },
      "height": 190,
      "width": 160,
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"category": "A", "value": 30}
        ]
      },
      "height": 190,
      "width": 160,
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}

thanks for the help

Can you provide a spec and desired outcome?

Hi, I attached a simple example as the real file contains sensitive information...for example : I would like to achieve that when "value" equals to 10, set the height to 100, when "value" equals 30 then to 200...
in real scenario I have a slicer in my report that is changing the x-axis of my chart...so based on slicer value I would like to set the height
thanks

I can get it working with a Single view but not Vconcat.
In this example the largest dim data dictates the chart height dynamically.
Maybe this will help you. Probably not ;)
You may have to switch over to Vega for this.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "A", "value": 10, "dim": 100},
      {"category": "B", "value": 80, "dim": 100},
      {"category": "C", "value": 7000, "dim": 300}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "extents", "expr": "extent(pluck(data('source_0'), 'dim'))"},
    {"name": "height", "expr": "extents[1]"}
  ],
  "width": "container",
  "autosize": {
    "type": "fit",
    "contains": "padding"
  },
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum"}
  }
}

